# HTML: completely useless tag

Tags: html, tags

I need completely dumb tag which does absolutely nothing. `div` breaks line and I wouldn't like to use `span` because I will put another elements inside this dump tag and I'm not sure if span is designed to contain other elements.

These two solutions came up to my mind:

1. Use span anyway
2. Use completely unused tag

but im not sure how it would work in older browsers.

PS: I already solved my problem by using divs, but I am still curious about this question.

Comment: What is your question, sir...

Comment: The difference between div and span is one is a [block level element](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) and the other is [inline](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html)

Comment: `span` can contain other tags...

Comment: span can contain inline elements

Comment: I have seen both ``<b>`` and ``<i>`` used for this sort of thing. Honestly, I would just use a span and either set it to ``display: inline-block`` or ``block``. That is the least "hackish" way of going about this.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301515.aspx `<completelyuselesstagFTW>`

Comment: useful answer, use `<div class="completely_useless">` and apply style that make it fit to your _completely useless_ definition

Comment: The reason you might want to do this is to avoid other CSS styles that are applied to spans or divs, without having to put a class on every the element every time you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `div` with an inline-block attribute? Might do what you need.

```
div{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, I'd like to address the comments underneath your question.

A `<span>` would indeed work fine for what you're doing. The only difference between a `span` and a `div` is that a `div` is, by default a *block* element while a `span` is an *inline* element by default. I would still use a `div` container in your case, however, because to me it makes more sense to wrap elements in a `div` over a `span`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any element really.  The thing you would have to remember is to make the `position: fixed;` which will take it out of the natural flow and set a `z-index: -10;`.  This would ensure it is always hidden in the background and the other elements would be on top of it.

You didn't specifically mention when you where trying to accomplish so this is just a first-round guess.